# how to bypass Access-Control-Allow-Origin for an API post request

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, cors

Am using ajax and jquery in my .net application , 
the consuming of the Payment api is by using ajax , 
this api has (basic auth + post type),
when i try to fire it i get :-

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'API URL' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

i have tried using , **JSONP** didn't work -> a pop appears asking my username and password ,
i have tried using this plugin  **jquery.ajax-cross-origin** , for proxy bypass 
didn't work -> its takes alot of time then same problem 
this my ajax code :

```
       $.ajax({
            // crossOrigin: true,
            url: "api url",

            type: "POST",     
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("name" + ":" + "password"));
            },                
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },
```

am figuring out that i can do something with .net adding a header or something , 
this have take a lot of time from me ,but still didn't reach solution .

Also , its working if i use a chrome plugin to enable CROS share , but this is not a production solution ,

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found solution ,
 its not the right way , but it can be better than installing the browser plugin to pybass CORS , 
solution is use a proxy , something like this :

```
         var proxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
        var url = "api url";

        // GET SESSION ID 
        $.ajax({
            url: proxy + url,
```